# How to make QOCI driver available for PyQt5

Tags: python, database, oracle, pyqt, driver

I'm trying to use `QOCI` driver to connect to Oracle Database, but the driver is not available. For this simple code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtSql

QtSql.QSqlDatabase.isDriverAvailable('QOCI')
```

I get `False`.

I tried checking the `PATH` environmental settings, and I see that there is `TNS_ADMIN` variable set to folder with driver file `oci.dll`:

```
C:\Atena\instantclient_11_2
```

but it's still unavailable.

I tried downloading the driver from Oracle site, setting it up according to Oracle instructions (changing the `PATH` variable to the new driver folder, copying TNSnames.ora file etc.), but still the driver is unavailable.

I want to have the driver available for PyQt5, load it, and the use it to connect to Oracle database.

Answer (score 1):

The OCI.DLL is included for example in instantclient-basic-windowsXXXXX.zip
Assume you have unzipped file to

```
C:\ORACLE\IC\12201\instantclient_12_2
```

to make it available for other applications, set in user environment

```
ORACLE_HOME=C:\ORACLE\IC\12201\instantclient_12_2
PATH=%PATH%;%ORACLE_HOME%
```

with this setting any application using OCI.DLL should find it.
Of course you have to install the right bitsize - i.e. if you application is 32bit, you need to install a 32bit Instant Client - if it is a 64bit App, you need 64bit instant client.

So - as far as I can see you need to build the QOCI manually. To do that, you need definetly the SDK package for instant client.

Sources on the web state that you need to include headers and libs from SDK - unfortunatly it looks like the QOCI still depends on Oracle Client 11.X - not instant client but regular client.

following libraries need to be used (last one is for client 12.x)

```
oci.lib ociw32.lib oraocci12.lib
```

on regular client

```
%ORACLE_HOME%\oci\lib\msvc
```

on instant client

```
%ORACLE_HOME%\sdk\lib\msvc
```

following headers need to be included

```
oci.h
```

on regular client

```
%ORACLE_HOME%\oci\include
```

on instant client

```
%ORACLE_HOME%\sdk\include
```

Unfortunatly there is no much support for MinGW so I cannot do that.

the "configure" command to prepare everything needs to include

```
-sql-oci -plugin-sql-oci
```

Comment: Copy oraociei10.dll from where to where? Can you be more specific?
Could rebuilding the Qt5 from source (on Windows) help with this issue?